# Bash associative array key from variable

Tags: bash, associative-array

In the follwoing script, parseTask sets global variables `topic` and `points` extracted from a given file. Then prints the task name (from the file name) and its topic.

```
BASE_DIR=/root/devops/tasks

function nextSection {
    if [ "$section" == "topic" ]; then
        section="points"
    else
        section="topic"
    fi
}

function parseTask {
    section=""
    while read line
    do
        if [ "$line" == "---" ]; then
            nextSection
            continue
        elif [ "$section" == "topic" ]; then
            topic=$line
        elif [ "$section" == "points" ] && [ "$line" != "" ]; then
            IFS=/; read -a fields <<<"$line"
            points=$((${fields[1]}-${fields[0]}))
        fi
    done < "$1/README.txt"
}

for task in $BASE_DIR/*
do
    parseTask "$task"
    if [ "$points" -eq 0 ]; then
        continue
    fi
    local taskName=${task:${#BASE_DIR}+1}
    echo "taskName: $taskName"
    echo "topic: $topic"
    echo
done
```

When I run it, I get the following (expected) output.

> taskName: awesome product function
>   topic: computer science
>
> taskName: calculate product
>   topic: arithmetic
>
> taskName: sum function
>   topic: computer science

I want to define a mapping from taskName to topic, so I changed it to

```
declare -A taskTopics
for task in $BASE_DIR/*
do
    parseTask "$task"
    if [ "$points" -eq 0 ]; then
        continue
    fi
    local taskName=${task:${#BASE_DIR}+1}
    echo "taskName: $taskName"
    echo "topic: $topic"
    echo
    taskTopics[$taskName]=$topic
done
```

But now I get an error:

> file.sh on line 13: /README.txt: No such file or directory
>   file.sh on line 41: taskTopics[$taskName]: bad array subscript

I could use any help with figuring out what is going on here.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://www.shellcheck.net/ and [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: One issue (which I think is the cause of your errors): you have also globally changed the value of `IFS` when you call `parseTask`. Use `IFS=/ read -a fields <<< "$line"` (with *no* semicolon). Related: *always* quote parameter expansions unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

One issue (which I think is the cause of your errors): you have also globally changed the value of `IFS` when you call `parseTask`. Use `IFS=/ read -a fields <<< "$line"` (with *no* semicolon). Related: *always* quote parameter expansions unless you have a very good reason not to.
                    – chepner